Slow performance decoding large images with Core Image
I'm building a camera app that does some post processing after the photo has been taken. With 12MP the processing is pretty good, but larger images 24MP is very slow.
I created a very simple example to demonstrate the issue, which is loading an image and the rendering it to data.
let context = CIContext()

let imageUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "12mp", withExtension: "jpg")!
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: imageUrl)

let ciImage = CIImage(data: data)!
            
let start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
            
let data = context.jpegRepresentation(of: ciImage, colorSpace: context.workingColorSpace!)
            
print(data?.count)
print("Resize Completed: " + String(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start))

Running this code on an iPhone 16 Pro with different images produces these benchmarks:

12MP => 0.03s
24MP => 1.22s
48MP => 2.98s

I understand that processing time will increase with resolution but it doesn't seem linear. I have tried setting different CiContext options such as .useSoftwareRenderer: false but it has made no difference.
From profiling the process it looks like the JPEG decoding is the bottle neck. This is for a 48MP Image:

Is there any way this can be improved?
Any help appreciated!

It looks like JPEG encoding is what you are measuring in your code. (The decoding is done with the code CIImage(data: data). JPEG compression/decompression is compute-intensive. You might try using Core Image to do the JPEG decompression and see if it is any faster, or do that work on a background thread so it doesn't block the UI.

@DuncanC How can I use Core Image to do the JPEG decompression? I can't find it in the docs.

Sorry, I should have said "Use Core GRAPHICS to decode the image." You could use the low-level CGImage method init(jpegDataProviderSource:decode:shouldInterpolate:intent:), or just the UIImage method init(contentsOfFile:). (The UIImage method almost certainly uses the CGImage initializer under the covers. A UIImage is a wrapper around a CGImage, and there are helper methods that convert back and forth between CGImage and CIImage.

Ah makes sense, I'll see if it improves performance.

Unfortunately these methods do not speed up the process. I also have the added complication of wanting to use a CIRAWFilter for iPhones that support ProRAW, so I'm not sure this method would have been helpful in that case.

I was afraid it would not speed things up, but figured it was at least worth a shot. I think you're facing the fact that JPEG compression/decompression is time-consuming. You should look to do that work on a background thread so you're not blocking the UI.

Yeah it's strange that it doesn't increase linearly with resolution though! Unless above a certain resolution it has to use a different code path but seems strange.

JPEG compression varies with the content of the image. An image with lots of solid colored areas compresses well, where an image with a lot of detail takes more time to compress and results in a larger final file.
